# Use CRON to import remote .sql file

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Before I get to into this I want to make sure my train of thought is on the right track.

The job I'm working on requires calendar software created in PHP to be installed on two servers and use a single mySQL database for information. I have the software up and running great on server A, but I can't get the code on server B to connect to the database (error regarding different password encryption techniques) that I am unable to overcome.

Now I assume if I use CRON to backup the database and save an .sql file on server A, I should be able to use CRON script to import that backup into mySQL on server B.

```
0,30    *   *   *   *   mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD database > database_backup.sql
```

and

```
0,35    *   *   *   *       mysql -h DB_HOST -u DB_USER -p'DB_PASSWORD' DB_NAME < /url/of/file/database_backup.sql
```

Is this anywhere close to right or should I go back to fighting with the remote database connection?

Comment: It would probably be easier to allow server B to access server A than to play this dangerous game of dumping and loading.

Answer (score 2):

You do realize that cron is just a scheduler, and simply executes whatever program you tell it to? cron has **NO** smarts beyond that. If you want to use a remote file, then it's up to **YOU** to fetch that file. That's not, never has been, and never will be, cron's job.

You would have to have, at minimum, something like:

```
* * * * (wget http://example.com/file.sql > file.sql && mysql < file.sql)
```

But then, you shouldn't be embedding such "complex" commands into the crontab anyways. YOu should put the full logic into a shell script, and then have cron invoke that script:

```
* * * * /path/to/script/get_sql_file_and_load_into_mysql
```